# JavaScript equivalent for jQuery .on() with additional selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, selector

Here is JSFiddle exapmle: https://jsfiddle.net/1a6j4es1/1/

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'green');
});
```

How can this code be rewritten in plain JavaScript?
Callback function should work even for new `td` elements inside the `table` element.

**Update**: I found out a very short and clean solution: https://jsfiddle.net/1a6j4es1/28/

```
function delegateSelector(selector, event, childSelector, handler) {

    var is = function(el, selector) {
      return (el.matches || el.matchesSelector || el.msMatchesSelector || el.mozMatchesSelector || el.webkitMatchesSelector || el.oMatchesSelector).call(el, selector);
    };

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    [].forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
        el.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
            if (is(e.target, childSelector)) {
                handler(e);                
            }
        });
    });
}

delegateSelector('table', "click", 'td', function(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table id="clickable" onclick="changecolor(this)" border=1>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<script>
    function changecolor(table)
    {
     document.getElementById("clickable").addEventListener("click",tableClicked);
      function tableClicked(e) {
       e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
     }
    }
</script>
```

This worked for me ..

Comment: Doesn't work when one of the cells contains child elements. Or when there are `<tr>` cells.

Comment: I fixed the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/1a6j4es1/27/

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to the element you wish to click on, and use this code:

```
document.getElementById("tableId").addEventListener("click", function(e){
e.target.style.background = 'green';
});
```

Comment: what if there is a span or div inside a td?

Comment: @charlietfl what do you want to do with them?

Comment: would want the parent `<td>` to change not the children. `target` might not be the `<td>

Comment: @charlietfl then instead of e.target, use document.getElementById("tableId") and you will get the specific element you want

Comment: that would change the whole table not a single `td`. What is needed is to walk up the dom from target and test for `td`. Current solution oversimplifies the situation

Comment: @charlietfl document.getElementById("tableId").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if( e.target.nodeName == "TD" ){
        e.target.style.background = 'green';
    }
});

Comment: updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/1a6j4es1/19/

Comment: still the same problem if `target` is a child node and isn't actually the `td`  https://jsfiddle.net/1a6j4es1/20/

Comment: @charlietfl You can recursively lookup the parent tree. this should work: https://jsfiddle.net/1a6j4es1/21/

Comment: now you are onto something